# Espaço entre título e tabela

Tags: latex

O título da minha tabela está muito distante da tabela em si, gostaria de saber algum modo de diminuir esse espaçamento.

Imagem: 
[image]

Código:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Cronograma de pesquisa}
    \label{cronograma}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c c c c c c c c}
            \hline 
            ATV & SET & OUT & NOV & DEZ & JAN & FEV & MAR & ABR & MAI & JUN & JUL & AGO \\
            \hline
            1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\             
            2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando `\vspace` serve para adicionar ou retirar espaçamentos verticais no LaTeX. Se for usado um número positivo, ele adiciona espaço. Se for usado um número negativo, ele retira.

No caso da tua tabela, eu retirei 5 milímetros entre a caption e a tabela em si. Veja o código abaixo e, logo em seguida, o resultado que obtive.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \caption{Cronograma de pesquisa}
    \vspace{-5mm}
    \label{cronograma}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c c c c c c c c c c c}
            \hline 
            ATV & SET & OUT & NOV & DEZ & JAN & FEV & MAR & ABR & MAI & JUN & JUL & AGO \\
            \hline
            1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\             
            2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, Marcus. Outro método que encontrei foi colocar o caption após \begin{center} e antes do \begin{tabular}. Não havia visto que tinha coloco fora.

Comment: Bom, ao menos fica aí um outro recurso caso tu precise alterar espaçamentos dentro do teu texto no LaTeX. O `\vspace` serve para as mais variadas situações, não apenas tabelas.